# Looking for an 8-bit microcomputer with a hardware-accelerated database

Tags: history, hardware, identify-this-computer, 8-bit-microcomputers, database

In some old video on YouTube a few years ago, I noticed a curious computer from the end of the 70s - early 80s. In the rack (half height), typical of minicomputers of those years, there was a 14" hard disk, an impressively massive power supply and a computer itself on several printed circuit boards.

If I do not change my memory, there was a system based on i8080 or Z80 CPU, peripheral controllers (printer and terminal), a hard disk controller on SSI/MSI chips and a certain hardware database accelerator with bit-slice ALU.

In general, a certain analogue of the middle-class systems from IBM, produced by some little-known USA company (start-up of those years probably).

Unfortunately, I did not succeed anent of anything about this system, and I ask for help. Looking for the history of this computer, description, documentation... Or at least a name for searching in Google.

Comment: Sure it was an 8080? The description sounds much like business computers from the 70s, like MAI et.al.

Comment: I'm not sure that was exactly the i8080 processor. But about the combination of an 8-bit processor itself (not terminal) and bit-slice accelerator I, however remembered well. But yes, somehow it looks like MAI BB line (Microdata corp) computers. Hm...

Comment: *Unfortunately, I did not succeed anent of anything about this system* 'succeed anent' doesn't make sense - please can you edit and correct this, to clarify what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: @TonyM - seems clear enough in context, no?   He didn't succeed in [finding out] anything concerning this system.

Comment: Sounds like an MAI BASIC/Four minicomputer - except that bit-slice processor in that case wasn't a "database accelerator" it was the actual CPU - custom instruction set (bytecode) for running BASIC (and another custom instruction set, bytecode, for running the compiler/decompiler which was written in TREE-META).  I don't remember there being an 8080/Z80 in there (don't remember one way or the other) but if there was it would have been a (multi-) terminal controller.

Comment: (Not sure what you meant by "Microdata Corp" ... explain?)

Comment: Using a bit slice ALU as a "database accelerator" sounds strange to me. Databases typically benefit much more from more and faster memory than from a faster ALU.

Comment: @davidbak, I used to work with [PERQ minicomputers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PERQ) back in the 1980s. The PERQ had a custom TTL main processor, and it had a Z80 that normally functioned as an I/O co-processor; but I knew of one user who reversed those roles. He had CP/M running on the Z80, and an application that used the main CPU as an "accelerator." Unfortunately, I forget pretty much all of the details of what the application actually did.

Comment: @SolomonSlow - interesting! wouldn't have thought of using a PERQ that way ... but I don't get what that has to do with a BASIC/FOUR mini??

Comment: @davidbak, Nothing other than that you mentioned that the BASIC/Four _might_ have used a microprocessor for some purpose. That and the fact that the topic was "hardware accelerator" caused a "retro" neuron to fire in my brain. Now, if only I could remember which person did it (Somebody from the Carnegie-Mellon University CS department's hardware lab, I think) or _why_ they did it (maybe just because, like Mt. Everest, It was there.)

Comment: @SolomonSlow - ok, it's interesting, i've this vague idea I've heard of other "backwards" uses of i/o processor vs main CPU, in some other context too ... I imagine the Mt Everest theory is actually quite strong for this kind of thing ...

Answer (score 6):

I believe you are referring to the seminal [CAFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Addressable_File_Store) system introduced by ICL in the 1970s.

This was a combination of a hard drive and a custom computer that performed database searches without the data leaving the hard drive. The initial implementation was literally built right onto the drive head. I can't be sure that the hardware included a bit-slice processor, but given the time that is hardly difficult to imagine (the AMD designs were widely used then).

The host computer would basically send a search term to the drive which would then return the matching records directly, without the need for all of the data to be streamed to the host to perform the matching there. This dramatically increased performance while at the same time freeing the host for other tasks like terminal handling.

Although test units were built in the 1960s, the first production systems were built in the early 1970s for British Telecom, which used them for phone number lookups. A newer version which used "standard microprocessors" was released in the early 1980s.

Comment: Remarkable device for that time!